# Get list all IP addresses connected to your server using Powershell / CMD

Tags: windows, powershell

***EDITED***
my goal:
get "total" list of IP's connected to port 80 in Windows server.

```
TOTAL  IP's
5      1.1.1.1
12     2.2.2.2
1      3.3.3.3
```

In CentOS, I found this

```sh
netstat -tn 2>/dev/null | grep :80 | awk '{print $5}' | cut -d: -f1 | sort | \
uniq -c | sort -nr | head
```

But if Windows server, is there any way to do that using PowerShell or `CMD`?

---

*I get one example, but it's not reaching my goal:*

```sh
netstat -n | find "80"
```

Credit for example: https://mkyong.com/linux/list-all-ip-addresses-connected-to-your-server/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Get-NetTCPConnection` is the PowerShell equivalent and creates a robust object you can filter to your needs.

In your example, you're getting all connections to port 80 on your device, here's what that looks like in PowerShell:

```
Get-NetTCPConnection |where RemotePort -eq 80

LocalAddress                        LocalPort RemoteAddress                       RemotePort State       AppliedSetting OwningProcess
------------                        --------- -------------                       ---------- -----       -------------- -------------
192.168.0.27                        51135     50.63.202.49                        80         CloseWait   Internet       12508
192.168.0.27                        51134     50.63.202.49                        80         CloseWait   Internet       12508
192.168.0.27                        51133     50.63.202.49                        80         CloseWait   Internet       12508
192.168.0.27                        51132     50.63.202.49                        80         CloseWait   Internet       12508
```

If you wanted to gather just the remote IP addresses, for instance:

```
Get-NetTCPConnection |where RemotePort -eq 80 |select RemoteAddress

RemoteAddress
-------------
50.63.202.49
50.63.202.49
50.63.202.49
50.63.202.49
50.63.202.49
50.63.202.49
```

If you need to group them to see how many sessions per IP, you can pipe into the `Group-Object` cmdlet like so:

```
Get-NetTCPConnection |where RemotePort -eq 80 |select RemoteAddress |
   group-object -Property RemoteAddress |select Name,Count

Name         Count
----         -----
72.21.91.29      1
23.35.182.63     6
```

Comment: thank you for replying, is it possible to also get "total" of following IP? example 
34 1.2.3.4 | 5 123.123.123.123. where 34 and 5 is "total"

Comment: PowerShell has a cmdlet called `Group-Object` that will give you totals like you'd like, i'll update the answer.  Remember to vote up any helpful answers and mark as answer as well.

Comment: thank you, this answer is really like what my goal is. and sorry i cannot vote up (i need min 15 reputation) :s

Answer (score 0):

One quick and dirty way to find TCP sessions connected to port 80 is

```
for /f "tokens=3" %a in ('netstat -n ^| find ":80 "') do @echo %a > filename.txt
```

You would obtain output similar to the following:

```
10.1.1.3:52025
10.1.1.3:53014
10.1.1.3:53039
10.1.1.3:53044
10.1.1.3:53066
```